# Page Grid With Banner Always in Third Row

Tags: css, frontend

I am trying to build a page that lists products in a grid, but with a third row that is always a banner (which spans the whole width of the page). Now when resizing the browser the number of products in a row changes (down to just 4 or 3 depending on the window size). The challenge is to ensure that the banner stays on the third row and that the product tiles float to the top or the bottom filling up the empty space.

I am looking for a pure CSS solution, but weren't able to come up with one (I have solved it using Javascript, but I'd like to remove it, because of performance reasons).

I have attached some images to illustrate my point:
[image: Grid Layout 5 Columns]
[image: Grid Layout 4 Columns]
[image: Grid Layout 3 Columns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little bit of research I found a solution utilizing the flexbox `order` property and the `nth-child` pseudo class.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="products">
  <div class="product">
    <h2>
      Product 1
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h2>
      Product 2
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h2>
      Product 3
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h2>
      Product 4
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h2>
      Product 5
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h2>
      Product 6
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h2>
      Product 7
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h2>
      Product 8
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h2>
      Product 9
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h2>
      Product 10
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="banner">
    <h2>
      Full width banner
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h2>
      Product 11
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h2>
      Product 12
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h2>
      Product 13
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h2>
      Product 14
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h2>
      Product 15
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.products {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.product {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 100px;

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      width: calc(100% / 3);

      // Show 6 product tiles before banner
      &:nth-child(-n+6) {
        order: 0;
      }

      &:nth-child(n+7) {
        order: 2;
      }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
      width: calc(100% / 4);

      // Show 8 product tiles before banner
      &:nth-child(-n+8) {
        order: 0;
      }

      &:nth-child(n+9) {
        order: 2;
      }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
      width: calc(100% / 5);

      // Show 10 product tiles before banner
      &:nth-child(-n+10) {
        order: 0;
      }

      &:nth-child(n+11) {
        order: 2;
      }
  }
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/smonusbonus/y6h5ocbx/13/) is the JSFiddle if you want to play around with it.